# Exception handling of async void methods

Tags: c#, exception, async-await

The following C# code results in unhandled exception. Why is the exception not caught by the catch statement? Can somebody explain the internals of exception handling of `async void` methods? Is there a way to catch exceptions for `async void` methods?

```
    static async void RunThings()
    {
        throw new Exception();
        await Task.Delay(500);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            RunThings();
            Task.CompletedTask.Wait();
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Caught!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Avoid `async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming). It makes sense only for event handlers

Comment: Because your task/method is running unobserved.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski But then, exceptions in event handlers will not be handled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is the exception not caught by the catch statement?

[Because it's `async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming).

> Can somebody explain the internals of exception handling of async void methods?

The `Task` in an `async Task` method represents the execution of that method. So when an `async Task` method raises an exception, that exception is used to fault the task.

`void` is an unnatural return type for `async` methods. Among other issues, there is nowhere to place the exception thrown by an `async void` method. So, any exceptions thrown out of an `async void` method will be raised directly on the `SynchronizationContext` that was active when the `async void` method started executing.

> Is there a way to catch exceptions for async void methods?

You could provide your own `SynchronizationContext`.

> But then, exceptions in event handlers will not be handled?

The "raise exceptions on the `SynchronizationContext`" behavior is intended to imitate the way exceptions work for event handlers. E.g. for a GUI application, the exception raised by a GUI event (`Button_Click`) will be forwarded to the same top-level application error handler (`Application.DispatcherUnhandledException`) whether the GUI event handler (`Button_Click`) is synchronous or asynchronous.